# Powershell Move Files To Directory - Maintain Paths?

Tags: powershell, command-line, terminal

Trying to make a simple backup script that will do as below:

Move the following

```
\source\example1.txt
\source\path\example2.txt
```

To

```
\dest\example1.txt
\dest\path\example2.txt
```

At the same time, renaming any files that already exist in `dest`.

My Code:

```
$src = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test1"
$dest = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test2"

Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Filter *.txt -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
$num=1
    $nextName = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $_.name

    while(Test-Path -Path $nextName)
    {
       $nextName = Join-Path $dest ($_.BaseName + " ($num)" + $_.Extension)    
       $num+=1   
    }

    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $nextName
}
```

This almost works but it flattens all files into one folder in the `dest`.
(`\source\path\example.txt` becomes `\dest\example.txt`)

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following *commented* code snippet could do the job:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $src -Filter *.txt -Recurse | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $num=1
    # ChildPath                                  ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
    $nextName = Join-Path -Path $dest -ChildPath $_.FullName.Replace("$src\", '')
    # effective destination for current file
    $destNew  = $nextName | Split-Path
    # create effective destination silently if necessary
    if ( -not (Test-Path -Path $destNew) ) {
        $null = New-Item $destNew -ItemType Directory
    }
    while(Test-Path -Path $nextName)
    {
       #                     ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
       $nextName = Join-Path $destNew ($_.BaseName + " ($num)" + $_.Extension)    
       $num+=1   
    }
    $_ | Move-Item -Destination $nextName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other method :

```
function Get-ItemNameWithNumberIfExist($NewPath, $BaseName, $Extension, $rang)
{

#build a new file name
if ($rang -eq 0)
{
    $NewFileName="{0}{1}" -f $NewPath, $BaseName, $Extension
}
else
{
    $NewFileName="{0}({1}){2}" -f $NewPath, $BaseName, $rang, $Extension
}

#build a new path file name (use combine for work on every SE)
$NewPathFile=[System.IO.Path]::Combine($NewPath, $NewFileName)

#recursive call if file exist
if (Test-Path -Path $NewPathFile)
{
    $rang++
    Get-ItemNameWithNumberIfExist $NewPath $BaseName $Extension $rang
}
else
{
    $NewPathFile
}

} 

$OldPath='C:\temp\tmp1\'
$NewPath='C:\temp\tmp2\'

Get-ChildItem $OldPath -file -Recurse | %{

$NewPath=$_.DirectoryName.Replace($OldPath, $NewPath)

#create directory without error if exist
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $NewPath -Force

#move item and rename if exist
move-item $_.FullName (Get-ItemNameWithNumberIfExist $NewPath $_.BaseName $_.Extension 0)

}
```